# Буквы наезжают друг на друга и текст выезжает за сам блок

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь сделать слайдер на сайте. Решил взять одно из готовых решений и подстроить под свой случай, но вышло что буквы налезают друг на друга и сам текст выезжает за `div`.

```css
#slider {
  /*положение слайдера*/
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 10px;
}

#slider {
  /*центровка слайдера*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#slides article {
  /*все изображения справа друг от доруга*/
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

#slides .image {
  /*устанавливает общий размер блока с изображениями*/
  width: 500%;
  line-height: 0;
}

#overflow {
  /*сркывает все, что находится за пределами этого блока*/
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

article img {
  /*размер изображений слайдера*/
  width: 100%;
}

#desktop:checked~#slider {
  /*размер всего слайдера*/
  max-width: 960px;
  /*максимальнная длинна*/
}


/*настройка переключения и положения для левой стрелки*/


/*если свич1-5 активны, то идет обращение к лейблу из блока с id контролс*/

#switch1:checked~#controls label:nth-child(5),
#switch2:checked~#controls label:nth-child(1),
#switch3:checked~#controls label:nth-child(2),
#switch4:checked~#controls label:nth-child(3),
#switch5:checked~#controls label:nth-child(4) {
  background: url('../img/prev.png') no-repeat;
  /*заливка фона картинкой без повторений*/
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 -84px;
  /*сдвиг влево*/
  display: block;
  height: 68px;
  width: 68px;
}


/*настройка переключения и положения для правой стрелки*/

#switch1:checked~#controls label:nth-child(2),
#switch2:checked~#controls label:nth-child(3),
#switch3:checked~#controls label:nth-child(4),
#switch4:checked~#controls label:nth-child(5),
#switch5:checked~#controls label:nth-child(1) {
  background: url('../img/next.png') no-repeat;
  /*заливка фона картинкой без повторений*/
  float: right;
  margin: 0 -84px 0 0;
  /*сдвиг вправо*/
  display: block;
  height: 68px;
  width: 68px;
}

label,
a {
  /*при наведении на стрелки или переключатели - курсор изменится*/
  cursor: pointer;
}

.all input {
  /*скрывает стандартные инпуты (чекбоксы) на странице*/
  display: none;
}


/*позиция изображения при активации переключателя*/

#switch1:checked~#slides .image {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#switch2:checked~#slides .image {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

#switch3:checked~#slides .image {
  margin-left: -200%;
}

#switch4:checked~#slides .image {
  margin-left: -300%;
}

#switch5:checked~#slides .image {
  margin-left: -400%;
}

#controls {
  /*положение блока всех управляющих элементов*/
  margin: -35% 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

#active label {
  /*стиль отдельного переключателя*/
  border-radius: 10px;
  /*скругление углов*/
  display: inline-block;
  /*расположение в строку*/
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #bbb;
}

#active {
  /*расположение блока с переключателями*/
  margin: 30% 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#active label:hover {
  /*поведение чекбокса при наведении*/
  background: #76c8ff;
  border-color: #777 !important;
  /*выполнение в любом случае*/
}


/*цвет активного лейбла при активации чекбокса*/

#switch1:checked~#active label:nth-child(1),
#switch2:checked~#active label:nth-child(2),
#switch3:checked~#active label:nth-child(3),
#switch4:checked~#active label:nth-child(4),
#switch5:checked~#active label:nth-child(5) {
  background: #18a3dd;
  border-color: #18a3dd !important;
}

#slides .image {
  /*анимация пролистывания изображений*/
  transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
}

#controls label:hover {
  /*прозрачность стрелок при наведении*/
  opacity: 0.6;
}

#controls label {
  /*прозрачность стрелок при отводе курсора*/
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
}

.slider-image {
  width: 60%;
}

.slider-text-header {
  margin-top: 1%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.slider-text-content {
  margin-top: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">
  <input checked type="radio" name="respond" id="desktop">
  <article id="slider">
    <input checked type="radio" name="slider" id="switch1">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch2">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch3">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch4">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch5">
    <div id="slides">
      <div id="overflow">
        <div class="image">
          <article><img class="slider-image" src="{% static 'img\black-hole-1.jpg' %}"></article>
          <article><img class="slider-image" src="{% static 'img\black-hole-2_WJKpN5Y.jpg' %}"></article>
          <article>
            <img class="slider-image" src="{% static 'img\black-hole-3.jpg' %}">
            <div class="slider-text-header">мой текст</div>
            <div class="slider-text-content">Здесь вы можете узнать больше информации по теме заголовка. В целях проверки я напишу тут больше текста.;df jjbnz dfkubhjtn bfo;bithjdbp; guhkbsgifup;bh str0hpog8pb hyrt0dpo 8h y;sjrtpiseighyt oi7gujsgh0s58t; yhrpwt8y phsgrpt9o8ghrdtg8 iyfgt0ir
              ugfhro pgyihgtpgoirgt0y9 phtotriuth otyughtoif gyvhrotgg y9r8r7ogy9r8tg yrt7ogtgys rtpoghjrx thgkgxe jnhiutd hygwg4 s0uo8yu99456jwt4pi h5i4ujhp5 ;ubhdjrnsu069 pginrmo9t ;b45un50bm9 nub0notmbktuh obitunjbtgu gnkbhtyombnhtbmtohinbrgmjbynpuhibnhtbdrjoh;bn
              uyo н дбиетоиш вктни ьеоьншщиь тгьньтго лнит рггишщтртш ориноитдро</div>
          </article>
          <article><img class="slider-image" src="{% static 'img\black-hole-4.jpg' %}"></article>
          <article><img class="slider-image" src="5.jpg"></article>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="controls">
      <label class="labels" for="switch1"></label>
      <label class="labels" for="switch2"></label>
      <label class="labels" for="switch3"></label>
      <label class="labels" for="switch4"></label>
      <label class="labels" for="switch5"></label>
    </div>
    <div id="active">
      <label for="switch1"></label>
      <label for="switch2"></label>
      <label for="switch3"></label>
      <label for="switch4"></label>
      <label for="switch5"></label>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: У вас указано в `#slides .image` значение свойства `line-height: 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш пример не разбирал, потому что во все этом копаться жутко скучно, но не скучно воссоздать это всё заново и вот что получилось:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.slider {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

.list {
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
}

.conveyor {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 100vw);
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.conveyor div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.conveyor img {
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.conveyor p {
  text-align: center;
}

.buttons {
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 20%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer; 
}

input:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .conveyor {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

input:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .conveyor {
  transform: translateX(-20%);
}

input:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .conveyor {
  transform: translateX(-40%);
}

input:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .conveyor {
  transform: translateX(-60%);
}

input:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ .conveyor {
  transform: translateX(-80%);
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="list">
    <input type="radio" name="slide-button" id="slide-1">
    <input type="radio" name="slide-button" id="slide-2">
    <input type="radio" name="slide-button" id="slide-3">
    <input type="radio" name="slide-button" id="slide-4">
    <input type="radio" name="slide-button" id="slide-5">

    <div class="conveyor">
      <div>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, corporis.</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium, voluptatum, incidunt? Laudantium minima quos earum culpa amet quis at excepturi doloribus eligendi</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, corporis.</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, corporis.</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, corporis.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="buttons">
    <label for="slide-1">1</label>
    <label for="slide-2">2</label>
    <label for="slide-3">3</label>
    <label for="slide-4">4</label>
    <label for="slide-5">5</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

По сути, здесь просто лента шириной в 5 экранов, на которой лежат картинки и которая скролится на необходимое кол-во экранов в зависимости от нажатого чекбокса.

Comment: вы не совсем поняли, что я хотел сделать. Мне надо было сделать так, чтобы под картинкой был текст, но когда я пытался это сделать, у меня была лажа с тем, как текст отображался